# RAID 10 Замена диска

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-server, raid, windows-server-2008-r2

Всем привет! Имеется сервер на Windows Server 2008 R2 c Intel RS2BL040 на борту. Был собран RAID 10. Один из 4-х дисков полетел. Заменили вышедший из строй диск. Теперь не понимаю что сделать, чтобы запустить диск в работу.

До замены диска было так:
[image: До замены диска было так]
Теперь стало так:
[image: Теперь стало так 1]

[image: Теперь стало так 2]

[image: Теперь стало так 3]

P.S. Прошу описать последовательность действий подробно, т.к. с таким сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: Ну а документации к проге нету?

Comment: Ребилд должен запускаться сам. Если нет - смотрите, что у Вас там и как контролирует и запускает.

Comment: Ребилд сам не запускается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заходим во вкладку Physical , затем, выбираем наш Raid контроллер. [image: physical]
Идем на вкладку Go to. Выбираем Controller -> Scan Foreign Configuration
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Появится окно с импортом конфигурации. Выбираем Import....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Жмем Yes
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]